# Manipulating a json file to find the line number and length of each line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, loops, maps

This is a JSON file and I would like to map through it so I can find out which line a string is on and how long that line is. for example `"hello world line one chapter one"` would output 1, 1,26 (chapter one, line one, 26 is the length). then       `hello world line three chapter two` would output 2, 3, 27 ( chapter 2, line 3, 27 is the length).

how would I write a javascript/react loop/map/filter to do this?

```
  "text": [
    [
      "hello world line one chapter one",
      "hello world line two chapter one",
      "hello world line three chapter one"
    ],
    [
      "hello world line one chapter two",
      "hello world line two chapter two",
      "hello world line three chapter two"
    ],
    [
      "hello world line one chapter three",
      "hello world line two chapter three",
      "hello world line three chapter three"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.
This uses [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and shows three different possible results, one using an array the other one using an object and a third which uses string concatenation. All three could be valid outputs and are semantically equivalent.

```js
const json = `{
    "text": [
        [
          "hello world line one chapter one",
          "hello world line two chapter one",
          "hello world line three chapter one"
        ],
        [
          "hello world line one chapter two",
          "hello world line two chapter two",
          "hello world line three chapter two"
        ],
        [
          "hello world line one chapter three",
          "hello world line two chapter three",
          "hello world line three chapter three"
        ]
      ]
    }`;

const parsed = JSON.parse(json);

const resultObjects = parsed.text.map((text, chapterIdx) =>
  text.map((line, lineIdx) => ({
    chapter: chapterIdx + 1,
    line: lineIdx + 1,
    length: line.length,
  }))
);

const resultArrays = parsed.text.map((text, chapterIdx) =>
  text.map((line, lineIdx) => [chapterIdx + 1, lineIdx + 1, line.length])
);

const resultStrings = parsed.text.map((text, chapterIdx) =>
  text.map(
    (line, lineIdx) => `${chapterIdx + 1}, ${lineIdx + 1}, ${line.length}`
  )
);

console.log("Result using JS objects:");
console.log(resultObjects);
console.log("Result using JS arrays:");
console.log(resultArrays);
console.log("Result strings:");
console.log(resultStrings);
```

#### Possible adjustments

##### Read from file

If you have the file on your disk you would of course first need to read the file using `fs.readFile()` in Node. Or you could `import` it in that case it will already be parsed and you don't need to parse it anymore.

##### Single array of results

If you would want the result in a single (not nested array) you would replace the first of two `map()` calls in each approach with [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

Expand this snippet to see the result.

```js
const json = `{
    "text": [
        [
          "hello world line one chapter one",
          "hello world line two chapter one",
          "hello world line three chapter one"
        ],
        [
          "hello world line one chapter two",
          "hello world line two chapter two",
          "hello world line three chapter two"
        ],
        [
          "hello world line one chapter three",
          "hello world line two chapter three",
          "hello world line three chapter three"
        ]
      ]
    }`;

const parsed = JSON.parse(json);

const resultObjects = parsed.text.flatMap((text, chapterIdx) =>
  text.map((line, lineIdx) => ({
    chapter: chapterIdx + 1,
    line: lineIdx + 1,
    length: line.length,
  }))
);

const resultArrays = parsed.text.flatMap((text, chapterIdx) =>
  text.map((line, lineIdx) => [chapterIdx + 1, lineIdx + 1, line.length])
);

const resultStrings = parsed.text.flatMap((text, chapterIdx) =>
  text.map(
    (line, lineIdx) => `${chapterIdx + 1}, ${lineIdx + 1}, ${line.length}`
  )
);

console.log("Result using JS objects:");
console.log(resultObjects);
console.log("Result using JS arrays:");
console.log(resultArrays);
console.log("Result strings:");
console.log(resultStrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Returning a list

Wasn't sure how you wanted the output exactly, this just gives you a flat array.

```js
let arr = {"text":[["hello world line one chapter one","hello world line two chapter one","hello world line three chapter one"],["hello world line one chapter two","hello world line two chapter two","hello world line three chapter two"],["hello world line one chapter three","hello world line two chapter three","hello world line three chapter three"]]}

let results = arr.text.flatMap((c,ci) => c.map((t,ti) => `${ci+1}, ${ti+1}, ${t.length}`))

console.log(results)
```

## Search for a specific string

This will find a specific line of text and return an array containing all items that match it.

```js
let arr = {"text":[["hello world line one chapter one","hello world line two chapter one","hello world line three chapter one"],["hello world line one chapter two","hello world line two chapter two","hello world line three chapter two"],["hello world line one chapter three","hello world line two chapter three","hello world line three chapter three"]]}

let stringToFind = "hello world line two chapter two";

let results = arr.text.flatMap((c,ci) => 
    c.map((t,ti) => t.includes(stringToFind) ? `${ci+1}, ${ti+1}, ${t.length}` : null)
    ).filter(x=>x)

console.log(results)
```

### Search Demo

Run the code snippet below and just start typing to see real-time results

```js
let arr = {"text":[["hello world line one chapter one","hello world line two chapter one","hello world line three chapter one"],["hello world line one chapter two","hello world line two chapter two","hello world line three chapter two"],["hello world line one chapter three","hello world line two chapter three","hello world line three chapter three"]]}

let findResults = (stringToFind) => {
  return arr.text
    .flatMap((c,ci) => 
          c.map((t,ti) => t.includes(stringToFind) ? `${ci+1}, ${ti+1}, ${t.length}` : null)
        )
    .filter(x=>x)
}

let input = document.getElementById('searchText'),
    results = document.getElementById('results'),
  doSearch = (searchString) => { results.innerText = findResults(searchString).join(" | "); }
```

```html
<input id="searchText" value="hello world line two chapter" oninput="doSearch(this.value)" />
<div id="results"></div>
```